# Add Data Programatically into custom column created on BigQuery Table

Tags: android, firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I have created a column in the events table on BigQuery to log some event information.

How can I add data into that specific column programmatically from a mobile application?

**This is my BigQuery Table**

[image]

**This is my Firebase schema**
[image]

**This is the code I tried so far**

```
Bundle params = new Bundle(); 
params.putString("image_name", name); 
params.putString("full_text", text); 
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("share_image", params);
```

Comment: Your question is very generic can you provide more details what you are Tring to do an example of what your tried so far

Comment: okay. I have an app and i have added the firebase event logging in that app. I have linked the app with bigquery so i can see my events data in bigquery auto generated table. now i have added new column in that table. I want to add data in that table just like event data is there.

Comment: i have tried to add the event logging using this                                          
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("image_name", name);
params.putString("full_text", text);
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("share_image", params);                                             and it store data in the table but now i wan to add data in that specific column of bigquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All [client libraries for BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries) are designed to be used in a trusted environment, such as your development machine, a server that you control, or Cloud Functions. There are no official SDKs for Android or iOS that I know of.

The simplest I can think of is to host code using one of these libraries in Cloud Functions (either through Firebase, or directly through the `gcloud` tooling) to insert data into BigQuery, and then call that Cloud Function from your mobile app. Be sure to secure access to that Cloud Function, so that only authorized users can insert data.

Comment: Okay. So if i use client librariers for bigquery. Does these libraries allow me to enter data into specific column of table "event". This "event" table is generated automatically when i log events from app using the logEvent() function as added in above code.

Comment: You'd typically create a new table for the new information, instead of updating the existing table. And then join the information from the two tables in a query. But if you really want to update the existing table, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/updating-data.